# unable to build or run ti info from appcellerator titanium setup

Tags: titanium

I am on a fresh updated install of Titanium Appcelerator, and I am unable to launch any ios demo. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Setup/Environment:

- iOS 9 Target
- Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.3.0.201509151348 Build: jenkins-appcelerator-rcp-master-322 (origin/master) Date: 15 September 2015, 13:48:44
- MacOS Host

ti info yields:

```

gcohen@:~$ ti info
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.3, Titanium SDK version 4.0.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:194
        throw e;
              ^
TypeError: Invalid Version: android.0.0
    at new SemVer (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:273:11)
    at compare (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:460:10)
    at gte (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:509:10)
    at cmp (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:526:22)
    at Comparator.test (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:599:10)
    at testSet (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:922:17)
    at Range.test (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:914:9)
    at satisfies (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/semver/semver.js:935:16)
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/version.js:156:33
    at Array.some (native)
---------------------------------------------
    at Object.run (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
    at find (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
    at q.process (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:809:21)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:358:17)
---------------------------------------------
    at async.setImmediate (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:110:15)
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:768:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)
    at _insert (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:753:11)
    at q.push (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:782:15)
    at findExecutable (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:113:8)
    at tasks.(anonymous function) (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/android.js:863:4)
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:524:25
---------------------------------------------
    at Object.run (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
    at find (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
    at q.process (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:809:21)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:358:17)
---------------------------------------------
    at async.setImmediate (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:110:15)
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:768:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)
    at _insert (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:753:11)
    at q.push (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:782:15)
    at findExecutable (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:113:8)
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/android.js:181:6
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/android.js:156:5
---------------------------------------------
    at async.setImmediate (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:96:15)
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:696:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at _insert (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:681:11)
    at q.push (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:708:15)
    at async.parallel.ndk (/Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/android.js:170:10)
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:524:25
    at /Users/gcohen/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:111:13
---------------------------------------------
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16)
    at CLI._fireHookCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:269:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:248:10
---------------------------------------------
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at detectMissingArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/cli.js:695:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:277:29
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
---------------------------------------------
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at CLI. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/cli.js:523:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:284:9)
    at _parallel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:688:9)
gcohen@:~$
```

I am trying to run either a blank wizard created app, or a demo that ships with the IDE, but I get this error no matter what when I go to run:

`Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.0.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
TRACE  | __command__ search paths:
[
  "/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package",
  "/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/node_modules",
  "/Applications/node_modules",
  "/node_modules",
  "/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/.npm/lib/node_modules"
]
DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/appc.js
DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 440ms /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/appc.js
DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/arrow/appc.js
log level set to "trace"
executing command "run"
set environment to {"registry":"https://software.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}
checking credentials for existing session
Attempting to load session info from config file
check if session is invalidated
session expiry 1442533156493 false
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ This is a Developer trial account. You may use this software for evaluation purposes. +
+ Once you are ready to go to production, upgrade at https://billing.appcelerator.com   +
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Arrow Cloud config file: /Users/gcohen/.acs
found Arrow Cloud login { mid: 'b754bb58143fbed982e2b8d45aff3aaf32689c32',
  publishPort: 443,
  publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
  username: 'geremy+titanium@pubnub.com',
  cookie: [ 'connect.sid=s%3AB4sWpL1Oyx8DjlyvJVolWlWA.I%2BP9AIOngeHGiyMtZKFk%2F3JzlF1IcPEQEYivsqSGkEw; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 17 Sep 2015 23:39:21 GMT; HttpOnly' ],
  defaultEP: 
   { publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
     publishPort: 443 } } , checking nodeACSEndpoint= https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com
Arrow Cloud cookie expiry [ 1442533161000 ]
session already loaded in opts.session
getCredentials() session:
{
  "ipaddress": "10.96.69.80",
  "username": "REMOVED",
  "password": "<OMITTED>",
  "session": "<OMITTED>",
  "nonce": "<OMITTED>",
  "environment": {
    "name": "production",
    "isProduction": true,
    "acsBaseUrl": "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "acsAuthBaseUrl": "https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "nodeACSEndpoint": "https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com"
  },
  "token": "<OMITTED>",
  "fingerprint": "b754bb58143fbed982e2b8d45aff3aaf32689c32",
  "fingerprint_description": "Mac OSX Serial Number: REMOVED",
  "org_id": 100067615,
  "expiry": 1442533156493
}
loading plugins for command "run"
run search paths:
[
  "/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package",
  "/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/node_modules",
  "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/node_modules",
  "/Applications/node_modules",
  "/node_modules",
  "/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/.npm/lib/node_modules"
]
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/appc.js
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 374ms /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/appc.js
run plugin: /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/arrow/appc.js
run plugin: /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/arrow
plugin "arrow" failed its "when" function check, skipping...
loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via function
loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via array
Duplicate option "colors" for command "run", removing...
executing command "run" with the following plugins:
["titanium"]
TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
TRACE  | session expiry 1442533156493 false
TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1442447830270
TRACE  | "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/bin/titanium" config -o json-object
WARN   | failed to parse titanium config file
WARN   | Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined
ERROR  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined
    at usedDifferentSDK (/Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:116:30)
    at /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:68:49
    at /Users/gcohen/.appcelerator/install/5.0.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/util.js:145:11
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:735:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12)`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you try to run the example using the terminal? Just typing `app run -p ios -C "iphone"` inside the project folder (then you have to choose the target emulator). Please do it without using Appcelerator Studio. Let me know the result!

Comment: Thanks Richard. I installed and uninstalled the Ti and Node 5 times and finally it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue ("Invalid Version: android.0.0"). 
The problem to me was that in the "PATH_TO_SDK/build-tools" folder there was a folder with a rare name (in my case "android_4.4") and all the other like "25.0.1".

So I removed it and everything worked fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Same for error `Invalid Version: app.0.0`. I left a spare file inside build tools folder.